# How can I insert a sub menu into a "ul" element without changing the parent "ul" or affecting its children?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, dom-manipulation

I have a `<ul>` element that contains multiple sub menus, and I want to insert a `<ul>` element into a `<li>` element inside the parent and increase the depth of the parent menu without affecting the siblings of the new element or making any other changes to the parent element.

Here is my HTML so far:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/lorem">lorem</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/ipsum">ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="/1"><i class="icon-credit-card"></i> Pricing Tables</a></li>
      <li><a href="/2"><i class="icon-gift"></i> Icons</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/grid">Grid</a></li>
  <li><a href="/slick">Slick</a></li>
  <li><a href="/slick_in_grid">Slick in Grid</a></li>
  <li><a href="/video">Videotest</a></li>
  <li><a href="/videogrid">Video in Grid</a></li>
  <li><a href="/audiogrid">Audio in Grid</a></li>
  <!--- here the new li ul  -->
  <li><a href="/formgrid">Form in Grid</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/langsub">langsub</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="/emt"><i class="icon-wrench"></i>EinganzlangerMenutext</a></li>
    <li><a href="/11"><i class="icon-credit-card"></i> Pricing Tables</a></li>
    <li><a href="/12"><i class="icon-gift"></i> Icons</a></li>
    <li><a href="/13"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Pages</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/21">Large Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="/22">Medium Image</a></li>
      <li><a href="/23">Masonry</a></li>
      <li><a href="/24">Double Sidebar</a></li>
      <li><a href="/25">Single Post</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
<!--- here the new /ul  /li -->
</ul>
```

This is my JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$("#main-menu").each(function() {
  //check region to move 
  var left = 0;
  var child = 0;
  var last_child = 0;
  var overflow = false;
  $("#main-menu > li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().left > left) {
      left = $(this).offset().left;
      child = $(this).index();
      alert($(this).attr("class") + $(this).html() + $(this).offset().left);
    } else {
      overflow = true;
    }
    last_child = $(this).index();
  });
  // insert li / ul and its closing at the end  
  if (overflow) {
    $("#main-menu > li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).index() == child) {
        $(this).before("<li><a href=\"#\">weitere...</a><ul class=\"sub-menu\">");
      }
      if ($(this).index() == last_child) {
        $(this).after("</ul></li>");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And this is an example of the outcome I'm looking for:

```
<ul class="before_change">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>            
</ul>
<ul class="after_change">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>
    new
    <ul>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>fife</li>            
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you add your html and css

Comment: @Geeky   html added, css does not matter

Comment: Can you explain little more of what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want add an additional <ul> or </ul>  at the points where is a comment in the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove and replace the elements instead of trying to change the raw HTML.
This is the finished JS code:

```
$("#main-menu").each(function() {
  //check region to move and clone it
  var left = 0;
  var child = 0;
  var last_child = 0;
  var overflow = false;
  var objects = Array();
  $("#main-menu > li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().left > left) {
      left = $(this).offset().left;
      child = $(this).index();
    } else {
      overflow = true;
    }
    // clone
    objects[$(this).index()] = $(this);
    last_child = $(this).index();
  });
  if (overflow) {
    $("#main-menu > li").each(function() {
      clone = ''
      for (o = child; o <= last_child; o++) {
        clone += '<li>' + objects[o].html() + '</li>';
      }
      if ($(this).index() == child) {
        $(this).replaceWith("<li><a href=\"#\">weitere...</a><ul class=\"sub-menu\"><li>" + clone + "</li></ul></li>");
      }
      if ($(this).index() > child) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
  }
});
```